# Creating TextView in a View in the Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and have a problem with the Navigation Drawer in Android Studio. I want to create dynamically a TextView in one of the Navigation Drawer's view. I cannot create a new TextView and I cannot search by id a TextView

```
public class StatoServer extends Fragment {

View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView tx = new TextView(this); //doesn't work this
    tx.setText("text that change dynamically with a function");
    container.addView(tx);
    myView = inflater.inflate(statoserver, container, false);
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: If you want your `TextView` to be part of that `Fragment`'s `View`, you want to add it to the `View` you're returning from `onCreateView()`. That is, add it to `myView` after it's inflated, not to `container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign any `LayoutParams` to your `TextView`, nor do you add it to the correct `ViewGroup`. It should be added to the `View` returned by `onCreatView()`. The following is tested and will work as an example of how to dynamically add a view:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        );
        ((ViewGroup)view).addView(textView);
        textView.setText("Some Text");
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **onCreateView** , here an example code on how you do it!

```
View v = new View(getActivity());

v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
    View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.Ausgabe);
    ((TextView)tv).setText("TestText");
    View pl = v.findViewById(R.id.PageLayout);
    TextView Paper = new TextView(pl.getContext());
    Paper.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Paper.setText("Inserted TestText");
    ((LinearLayout)pl).addView(Paper);
return v;
```